# Auto center with CSS with one exception

Tags: html, css

I have a design like that:
[alt text http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/8647/designiq.jpg](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/8647/designiq.jpg)

All my auto centered content has the following CSS:

```
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
```

Inside this auto centered content is a DIV-Element that should have a width of the full browser width.

What's the best solution to make the 100%-DIV?

`position: absolute /* or fixed */` is not that what I want to have,
because the content-height above the 100%-DIV is not every time the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Boxes</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper div.width_960 {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-left: 2px #000 solid;
    border-right: 2px #000 solid;
}
#wrapper div.width_full {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}   

-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="width_960">
        <p>demo</p>
        <p>demo</p>
        <p>demo</p>
        <p>demo</p>
        <p>demo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="width_full">
        <p>demo full</p>
        <p>demo full</p>
    </div>
    <div class="width_960">
        <p>demo</p>
        <p>demo</p>
        <p>demo</p>
        <p>demo</p>
        <p>demo</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a width is a one-way in CSS; you instantly lose the information of the parent's width.

To put it in a nutshell: *You can't* re-set a div inside a constrained div to the window's width with *CSS only*. With JavaScript, and assuming that the parent has no `overflow:hidden`, you could do this:

- set the child's width to window.innerWidth and
- set the child's left and right margin to -(window.innerWidth/2 - parentDivs_width)

like, e.g. for a window size of 800px:

```
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#child {
  /* set these with JS */
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 -250px;
}
```

The more trivial solution is to move the child div out of its parent and position it and the parent with negative top and bottom margins. (`position:absolute` won't work, because it's the same, you lose the information about the width.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a nasty ugly trick, but [here](http://jsbin.com/ifizo/2/edit) is one way, without any Javascript.

Basically, you make a separate absolutely positioned background element sized to cover any possible window.

**EDIT**: Fixed to handle multiple lines.

```
div.FullWidth {
  position:relative;
}
div.FullWidth .Background{
  position: absolute;
  left:-2048px;
  z-index:-1;
  width: 4096px;
  height:100%;

  background:#999;
}
div.FullWidth .Content {
  text-align: center;
  font-size:larger;
  color: red;
}



<div class="FullWidth">
  <div class="Background">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="Content">
    Hello!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an element wider than it's parent. You have to put it out of the flow.
`position:absolute` seems the answer, if you don't specify the top position it will take its position in the flow.

```
position:absolute;
width:100%;
left:0px;
```

Comment: Actually, you can have an element wider than its parent if it has negative margins. The problem is knowing what size negative margins to use.

Comment: Sure. What I meant is that a with of 100%, is necessarily the width of the direct parent (if you specify a width >100% you have also a child wider than its parent).